# T4 access list of properties with a certain annotation

Tags: c#, t4

access in t4 file properties with [key] annotation for example in ownedAttributes and navigableOwnedEnds

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think he just wants the properties with a certain attribute

Comment: i want to access that list in a T4 template. exactly from this.Element.OwnedAttributes; that figures in the template since there no intellinsense i cant seem to figure out if i can even use reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer that i was looking for

```
foreach(IProperty attribute in this.Element.OwnedAttributes)
{
  string attributeList = GetProperty(attribute, "property", "ClrAttributes");
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributeList))
  {
    //attributeList now will contain the attribute put in 
    //Streotypes>C# property>ClrAttributes
  }
}
```